# py2exe executable doesn't flush stdout properly

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, stdout, py2exe

I have a `python` script that prints some 5-digit numbers. I call this script through a `Qprocess` and read its output which I use later on.
On windows the script is packaged into an executable with `py2exe` and the executable is called.

When I ran either the executable, or the script from a terminal, the output is fine, but when I call the executable through the `Qprocess`, I get garbage.

The part of my script that prints is like this

```
print number
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I tried replacing `print` with `sys.stoud.write(number)` and also with `sys.stoud.write(number + '\n')` but with no success.

my `py2exe` script is :

```
setup(
    console=['number.py'],
    options = {
        'py2exe' : {
        'bundle_files': 1,
        'compressed': True
        }   
    },
    zipfile = None
)
```

I also tried changing `console=['number.py']` to `windows=['number.py']`, 
also with no success.

I know of `-u` switch of `python`, but I need to have it as an executable and I'm also not sure if this will work after all.

I have searched both on SO and google but everyone suggests using `sys.stdout.flush()` which is not enough for my case.

When I checked the output using a logger, I could see that the size of the output was different with a range from 6 characters to 11 incremented by 1 and then again from 6 to 11 and so on.

I' using Python 2.7 and the Qt is 4.8, I tested on Windows 7 and 8. On Linux everything runs smoothly.

I've wasted almost a whole day on this, I would appreciate any help

---

I also tried using `\r\n` when using `sys.stoud.write()`, but this didn't work too.

Trying to get this to work, I replaced the call to the executable with the call to the `python` script using the `-u` switch <`python -u myscript.py`> and it seems to work fine and the size of the output is always 6. 
Why is this ?

---

Looking at the [options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) provided by py2exe, I saw that there is the `unbuffered` option which says that when `True` unbuffered `stdout` and `stderr`(which I thought is unbuffered by default) are used.

> unbuffered: if true, use unbuffered binary stdout and stderr

I set `'unbuffered': True` in `setup.py` and this didn't work either.

Comment: `\r\n`? Windows doesn't use a plain `\n` for line endings.

Comment: @MarcB I tried this too, but doesn't seem to work,

Comment: `number` is invalid parameter , you can't access parameter if not defined any pointer. Short way is `call executable with an parameter`(just use `sys.argv` inside of your executable).(**Alloc**, **Malloc** ?)

Comment: Maybe your `Qprocess` is no reading the standard output correctly, try to focus on the output of the process in the `Qprocess` instead of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `os.fsync(sys.stdout.fileno())`.

Reference: [os.fsync(fd)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync)

> Force write of file with filedescriptor fd to disk. On Unix, this calls the native fsync() function; on Windows, the MS _commit() function.
>
> If you’re starting with a Python file object f, first do f.flush(), and then do os.fsync(f.fileno()), to ensure that all internal buffers associated with f are written to disk.